# List<Object> on SolrJ. Saving data to SOLR database gives Item@53c6f96d

Tags: java, spring-boot, solr, solrj, listobject

I have a problem when trying to save SolrJ object to SOLR database. I am using schemaless config at the beginning of project and that's what I've got inside a solr database:

```
{
        "name":["Person"],
        "items": 
        [".....package......model.Item@53c6f96d"],
        "id":"7e733b4b-d2be-4feb-b9f7-9f2e6a367b4e",
        "_version_":1655159878647283712}]
}
```

Here is my class:

```
@SolrDocument(solrCoreName = "core")
public class Resource {
    @Id
    @Field
    String id;
    @Field
    String name;
    @Field
    List<Item> items;

}
```

And Item class:

```
@SolrDocument(solrCoreName = "core")
public class Item {
    Map<String, String> systemFields;
    Map<String, String> dataFields;
}
```

Could you please propose a solution how can I push List of Object where I have two Maps to solr database?

Comment: What is your goal in relation to how the `Item` object should be indexed? Solr has no (direct) Map support built in - is your goal to get a JSON-ish structure with child documents/hierarchy?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I would like to obtain. Document inside the database with "JSON-ish" structure